# Ruby 1.9.3 - How does CSV.table know if no headers are in a CSV file?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have been doing some testing with `CSV.table`. I have two small and almost identical CSV files, however one is missing the header row.

When I run `CSV.table` against the CSV file with the header row, everything works as expected.

When I run it against the CSV file without the header row I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `encode' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried this with different types of data, with different types of headers, and get the same results.

I am curious to the magic of `CSV.table`. If I use `CSV.parse` with headers set to true, then it always makes the first row be headers no matter what. So, I have been using `CSV.table` to check if a CSV file being imported has a header row but I am not too comfortable with this because I don't understand if or when it will or will not work the way I'm using it.

```
begin
  CSV.table(csv_file_path)
rescue
  # Add error to log or something.
end
```

Does anyone know?

P.S. I've already read through this and the source code it provides on each method - http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't any magic involved, and it won't work for you in general.

As you can see [from the source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-table), `table` literally just calls `read` with `headers: true`. But it also converts the header to symbols (`header_converters: :symbol`) and this is the key to why it appears to work.

You get an error without headers because you have a blank column in your first row of data (something like `a,b,,d,e`). The blank gets read in as `nil`, and since `nil` can't be converted to a symbol, it blows up.

Try it with some data that doesn't have a blank in the first row - you'll see that `table` will treat that row of data as headers just like any of the other methods.

Comment: Thanks @andy-h I had a similar situation when I run `contents = CSV.open "languages.csv", headers: true, header_converters: :symbol` I got this error: `undefined method 'encode' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. It's complaining about `header_converter: :symbol` method. After reviewing "languages.csv" file I found it's header starts with " " a space. Removing that space solved that issue.

Comment: **Correction.** I meant I was missing a space at the first row `",name,address, ...."` when I added space like so `" ,name,address, ...."` I was able to run my code.